# If $M\otimes M^\vee\rightarrow \operatorname{End}(M)$ is an isomorphism then $M$ is reflexive (hence dualizable).

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

> Let $A$ be a (commutative if necessary) ring and $M$ an $A$-module. Suppose that the map
> \begin{align}M\otimes M^\vee&\longrightarrow \operatorname{End}(M) \\ m\otimes \phi(\cdot)&\longmapsto m\phi(\cdot)\end{align} is an isomorphism. Is it true that then the canonical map $M\longrightarrow (M^\vee)^\vee$ has to be an isomorphism?

Here $M^\vee=\operatorname{Hom}(M,A).$

**Context:**

In a monoidal category there is a concept of *[dualizable object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object)*. Following [Duality, Trace and Transfer by Dold, Puppe](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/dold-puppe2.pdf), if one takes the category to be $A$-Mod, a corresponding *dualizable module* is a reflexive module (that is, $M\overset{\sim}{\rightarrow} (M^\vee)^\vee$) in which $M\otimes M^\vee$ is canonically self dual. But if $M$ is reflexive then $$\operatorname{End}(M)=\operatorname{Hom}(M,M)=\operatorname{Hom}(M,\operatorname{Hom}(M^\vee,A))=\operatorname{Hom}(M\otimes M^\vee,A)=(M\otimes M^\vee)^\vee$$
Hence, canonically self dual is equivalent to $M\otimes M^\vee\cong \operatorname{End}(M)$ under reflexivity. Hence, if we have the implication above, a *dualizable module* would be exactly the modules in which $M\otimes M^\vee\cong \operatorname{End}(M)$ is an isomorphism, which I think would be very nice.

A remark, there is a characterization of dualizable modules, they are exactly the finitely generated projective modules over $A$ (Here $A$ is not necesarilly commutative). Hence, a possible counterexample should be either non projective or non finitely generated.

Comment: The answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2606969/400 to the second linked question also answers this one when $M$ is finitely generated by giving a reference to a paper that proves $M$ has to be projective. $M$ being finitely generated is necessary because the image of $M\otimes M^\vee\in\mathrm{End}(M)$ consists of endomorphisms with finite-dimensional image only, so lacks the identity morphism when $M$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov You are right, I just noticed it! and I wrote all the ideas as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to do it using the ideas in the proof of the reference in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2606969/124875) found by Vladimir Sotirov. Here it is the final conclusion:

**Theorem.** For a ring $A$ and a module $M$ the following are equivalent:

1. $X \otimes M^\vee\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(M,X)$ is an isomorphism for any module $X$.
2. $M\otimes M^\vee\rightarrow \operatorname{End}(M)$ is surjective
3. $M$ is finitely generated and projective
4. $M$ is a dualizable object in $(A$-Mod$,\otimes)$.

Under these condictions $M$ is a *dualizable module*. In particular, $M$ is reflexive.

*Proof:*

**1 implies 2:** Take $X=M$

**2 implies 3:** By surjectivity there are $\{m_i\}_i, \{\varphi_i\}_i$ such that $1_M=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes \varphi_i$. Then as
$$m=1_M(m)=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\otimes \varphi_i(m) \quad \forall m\in M,$$
$M$ is generated by $\{m_i\}$ and the pair $(\{m_i\}_i, \{\varphi_i\}_i)$ is a [projective basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module#Dual_basis), so the module is finitely generated and projective.

**3 implies 1:** The map is an isomorphism when $M=A^n$. Moreover, if it is an isomorphism for $A^n=N\oplus N'$, then it is an isomorphism for each direct summand $N,N'$.

The fact that $M$ is a dualizable object in this case was the comment in the question, and the fact that $M$ reflexive is similar to 2 implies 3 above.